# PyQt5 Custom Widgets are Opening in a New Window

Tags: python, pyqt5, project

I am currently attempting to make a custom widget for a project I am doing, but I am having a problem where the widget keeps showing up in a new window. I am not sure what is causing this, so while I try to do more research, I thought I might just come here and ask for help. This is the custom widget that I am making.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QPushButton, QLineEdit, QStackedLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget )
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class PythonMakeVariable(QWidget):
    return_pressed = pyqtSignal()
  
    def __init__(self):
        super(PythonMakeVariable, self).__init__()
        
        self.screens = QStackedLayout()
        name_screen = QVBoxLayout()
        value_screen = QVBoxLayout()
    
        name_screen.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        name_screen.setSpacing(0)
        value_screen.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        value_screen.setSpacing(0)
    
        self.name_line = QLineEdit()
        self.name_line.setPlaceholderText('Enter the name of the variable.')
        self.name_line.setFixedHeight(75)
        self.name_line.returnPressed.connect(self.on_name_return_click)
        name_screen.addWidget(self.name_line)
    
        name_continue = QPushButton('Continue')
        name_continue.setFixedHeight(50)
        name_continue.clicked.connect(self.on_name_return_click)
        name_screen.addWidget(name_continue)
    
        self.value_line = QLineEdit()
        self.value_line.setPlaceholderText('Enter a value')
        self.value_line.setFixedHeight(75)
        self.value_line.returnPressed.connect(self.on_value_return_click)
        value_screen.addWidget(self.value_line)
    
        value_continue = QPushButton('Continue')
        value_continue.setFixedHeight(50)
        value_continue.clicked.connect(self.on_value_return_click)
        value_screen.addWidget(value_continue)
    
        name_widget = QWidget()
        name_widget.setLayout(name_screen)
        self.screens.addWidget(name_widget)
    
        value_widget = QWidget()
        value_widget.setLayout(value_screen)
        self.screens.addWidget(value_widget)
        
    def on_name_return_click(self):
        if len(self.name_line.text()) == 0:
            return
        self.screens.setCurrentIndex(1)
            
    def on_value_return_click(self):
        self.return_pressed.emit()
        
    def get_input(self):
        def is_mathmatic(string):
            math = ['-', '+', '*', '/', '.', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ,'7' ,'8', '9', '0']
            return all([c in math for c in string])
        def is_list_dict(string):
            list_dict = ['[', ']', '{', '}']
            return any([c in list_dict for c in string])
        if is_mathmatic(self.value_line.text()) or is_list_dict(self.value_line.text()):
            return f'{self.name_line.text()} = {self.value_line.text()}\n'
        else:
            return f'{self.name_line.text()} = "{self.value_line.text()}"\n'
```

I am not sure if that is the problem, though. I have tried troubleshooting that part of the program, and I can't seem to find out what specifically is causing it. Here is the main file that attempts to use the file.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    # constructor that takes the window size
    def __init__(self, win_size):
        # calls super class constructor
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # names the window
        self.setWindowTitle('Code Builder')
        
        # sets the minimum and maximum size of the window.
        self.setMaximumSize(win_size)
        self.setMinimumSize(int(win_size.width()/4*3), int(win_size.height()/4*3))
        
        # this will set the windows icon
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Code Builder Logo.png'))
        
        self.code = []
        self.vars = []
        self.ind = []

        # creates the layouts for the start screen.
        # the stacked layout is how i will be switching from screen to screen
        self.screens = QStackedLayout()
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.language_choice_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.coding_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        # creating a qlabel that will allow me to put my background in it.
        background = QLabel()
        background.setPixmap(QPixmap('Code Builder Logo.png'))
        background.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(background)
        
        # creating an exit button that will end the program.
        exit_button = QPushButton('Exit')
        # on press, exit_click function is called
        exit_button.clicked.connect(self.exit_click)
        # adds this to the button layout.
        self.button_layout.addWidget(exit_button)
        
        # creates the button that will start the program and bring you to the password page.
        start_button = QPushButton('Use the Code Builder')
        # on click, start_click function is called
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_click)
        # adds this to the button layout.
        self.button_layout.addWidget(start_button)
        
        # adds the button layout to the main screen layout.
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.button_layout)

        # stacked layout do not allow you to add layouts, so i need to make it into a widget
        main_layout_widget = QWidget()
        main_layout_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        # now that it is a widget, i will add it to the stacked layout.
        self.screens.addWidget(main_layout_widget)
        
        # here is where i make the layouts for the password screen.
        password_screen = QVBoxLayout()
        details = QHBoxLayout()
        self.text_editors = QVBoxLayout()
        
        # creates the header label.
        password_label = QLabel('CODE BUILDER: LOGIN')
        # changes the font, font size, and bolds it.
        password_font = QFont('Helvetica [Cronyx]', 35, QFont.Bold)
        password_label.setFont(password_font)
        # sets the background color to dark red.
        password_label.setStyleSheet('''color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
                                     background-color: QLinearGradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgb(33, 161, 121), stop: 1 rgb(251, 159, 137));''')
        # fixes the height to 150 px.
        password_label.setFixedHeight(150)
        # aligns the text and adds the widget to the top of the layout.
        password_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        password_screen.addWidget(password_label)
        
        # the details layout is going to allow me to easily center the password page.
        # this part sets the margins so I can precisely put everything into place.
        details.setSpacing(0)
        details.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        # creates a label that will allow me to tell the user whether they put the right password or not.
        self.label = QLabel('')
        lbl_font = QFont('Helvetica [Cronyx]', 10)
        self.label.setFont(lbl_font)
        # sets a fixed height so the label doesn't move anything else when the text is added.
        self.label.setFixedHeight(200)
        # aligns the text in the center bottom of the label.
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)

        # prompts the user for their username.
        username = QLineEdit()
        # sets the background text for the prompt.
        username.setPlaceholderText('Username')
        # sets the font.
        up_font = QFont('Helvetica [Cronyx]', 15)
        username.setFont(up_font)
        # when return is pressed, it will call the return_pressed function.
        username.returnPressed.connect(self.return_pressed)
        
        # prompts the user for the password.
        self.password = QLineEdit()
        # sets the uneditable text.
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Password')
        # sets the font.
        self.password.setFont(up_font)
        # makes it so you cannot see the text being written.
        self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        # when return is pressed, it again calls the return_pressed function.
        self.password.returnPressed.connect(self.return_pressed)
        
        # adds all of the widgets to the text editors layout.
        self.text_editors.addWidget(self.label)
        self.text_editors.addWidget(username)
        self.text_editors.addWidget(self.password)

        # sets the margins for the text editor widgets.
        # setSpacing sets the interior margins.
        self.text_editors.setSpacing(50)
        # setContentMargins sets the margins between the layout and the next object.
        self.text_editors.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        # creates a blank color for better margins.
        c1 = Color(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # sets a fixed width of the margins.
        c1.setFixedWidth(500)
        # adds the margins.
        details.addWidget(c1)
        # makes the text editors layout into a widget and adds it to the details layout.
        text_widget = QWidget()
        text_widget.setLayout(self.text_editors)
        details.addWidget(text_widget)
        # adds the other side of the margins.
        details.addWidget(c1)
        
        # adds the details layout to the password layout.
        password_screen.addLayout(details)
        
        # adds blank space to the bottom of the screen.
        password_screen.addWidget(Color(0, 0, 0, 0))
        
        # adds a footer
        footer = QLabel('Made by Shade Burgess')
        # aligns the footer in the center
        footer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        # sets the background color and height
        footer.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);')
        footer.setFixedHeight(35)
        # adds it to the bottom of the password screen layout
        password_screen.addWidget(footer)

        # sets the margins of the password screen layout
        password_screen.setSpacing(0)
        password_screen.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        
        # makes the password layout into a widget and adds it to the screens.
        password_widget = QWidget()
        password_widget.setLayout(password_screen)
        self.screens.addWidget(password_widget)
        
        header = QLabel('Choose supported Language:')
        header.setFixedHeight(250)
        header_font = QFont('Helvetica [Cronyx]', 60)
        header.setFont(header_font)
        header.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.language_choice_layout.addWidget(header)
        
        py_lang = QPushButton('Python')
        py_font = QFont('Helvetica [Cronyx]', 30)
        header.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        py_lang.setFont(py_font)
        py_lang.clicked.connect(self.py_click)
        self.language_choice_layout.addWidget(py_lang)
        
        self.language_choice_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self. language_choice_layout.setSpacing(0)
        
        lang_choice_widget = QWidget()
        lang_choice_widget.setLayout(self.language_choice_layout)
        self.screens.addWidget(lang_choice_widget)
        
        self.code_terminal = QScrollArea()
        self.code_terminal.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Shadow)
        self.lines = QLabel(*self.code)
        self.code_terminal.setWidget(self.lines)
        self.coding_layout.addWidget(self.code_terminal)
      
        code_widget = QWidget()
        code_widget.setLayout(self.coding_layout)
        self.screens.addWidget(code_widget)
        
        # makes the screens layout to the central widget
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.screens)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
    
    # when called, the program will stop
    def exit_click(self):
        sys.exit()
        
    # when called, the program will move to the password screen
    def start_click(self):
        self.screens.setCurrentIndex(1)
        
    # will check the password prompt to see if it matches the password
    def return_pressed(self):
        if self.password.text() != '123':
            # if it doesn't match, we change the placeholder labels text to this.
            self.label.setText('Incorrect password, try again.')
        else:
            # otherwise, it will move to the next screen.
            self.screens.setCurrentIndex(2)
    
    def py_click(self):
        self.py_var_maker = PythonMakeVariable()
        self.py_var_maker.return_pressed.connect(self.py_close)
        self.screens.setCurrentIndex(3)
        self.coding_layout.addWidget(self.py_var_maker)

    def py_close(self):
        self.code.append(self.py_var_maker.get_input())
        self.lines.setText(*self.code)
        self.py_var_maker.setParent(None)
```

Any answer helps me learn, so if you know anything, please respond. Thanks.

I have tried troubleshooting a lot of the custom widget class, but I can't do much without erroring the whole program. There is a lot of unnecessary stuff in the main file, but I just wanted to give everyone the full context. I think there is something with the initialization of the widget or something that causes it to open in a new window.

Comment: You're never setting the stacked layout for the `PythonMakeVariable` widget. Change to `self.screens = QStackedLayout(self)`, or just inherit from QStackedWidger instead of QWidget and directly use `self.addWidget()`.